# IE Issue- Textarea always display text in one string without line breaks

Tags: internet-explorer, textarea, line-breaks

I am loading a text file using Jquery load() function in to Textarea section on the page. Able to display the text as expected in all the browsers and also FFox and chrome is displaying the text with line-endings without problem but IE is displaying all the text without any line breaks. Please advise. Here below is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#contentArea").load("test.txt");
});
</script>

<textarea id="contentArea"  rows="12" cols="80" disabled="yes" style="color:#663300;font-size:95%;background:#F5F5F5;line-height:25px;border:0px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Trebuchet MS;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you set the value of the Textarea to the contents of the file IE will see the line breaks as well.

so:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.get('test.txt', function(contents) {
           $("contentArea").val(contents);
     },'text');
  });
```

HTH.